# Coldfusion Server with MS SQL 2008 R2 - Database permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, coldfusion

I have a `Coldfusion` server with a lot of websites and an `MS SQL Server 2008 R2` connected with the webserver.
The issue is that all datasources are connected to SQL with the **sa** which is wrong.

So I tried to create a new user for each website on the SQL with permission on it's own database only. I am creating a new user but it asks also for login? Should I create a new login and a new user for each website?
Also what permissions a CF website will need in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a new login or changing a login in SQL, be sure to map it to one or more databases.

[image]

Give it a schema (`dbo` is default) and give him the appropriate rights in every database.